# How to show information about fields in sharepoint site creation

Tags: sharepoint, office365

i want to show Information for all the fields in the site creation form
[information of these fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPzgu.png)

as i'm completely new any help will be thankfull

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show "You can't leave this blank" alert in all fields, you could set the option "**Require that this column contains information**" to "**Yes**".

[image]

[image]

This will make these columns mandatory, and if you click on the field without filling in a value in this column, an alert message will be displayed below the text box.

If you create the site with [site scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-overview#anatomy-of-a-site-script), specify following field attribute value to true:

```
"isRequired": true
```